# Python and QML button integration not working

Tags: python-3.x, qml, pyside6

I have the main.py file below

```
import sys
from PySide6.QtCore import QObject, Signal, Slot
from PySide6.QtWidgets import QApplication
from PySide6.QtGui import QGuiApplication
from PySide6.QtQml import QQmlApplicationEngine

class ButtonHandler(QObject):
    @Slot()
    def handleButtonClicked(self):
        print("Hello")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QGuiApplication(sys.argv)
    engine = QQmlApplicationEngine()

    button_handler = ButtonHandler()
    engine.rootContext().setContextProperty("buttonHandler", button_handler)

    engine.load("main.qml")

    if not engine.rootObjects():
        sys.exit(-1)

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

and main.qml file as follows

```
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Window
import QtQuick.Controls 6.3

Window {
    id: window
    width: 640
    height: 480
    visible: true
    title: qsTr("Hello World")

    Button {
        id: button
        x: 248
        y: 234
        width: 155
        height: 34
        text: qsTr("HI")

        signal buttonClicked()

        onClicked: buttonClicked()
    }
}
```

The problem is the app runs fine but whenever i click the button i dont see the "Hello" message in my console
if there is anyway to fix that, Thanks

Comment: Try `buttonHandler.handleButtonClicked()`.

Comment: @smr on the qml file?

Comment: If we consider `buttonHandler` as your global object passed to QML, then `buttonHandler.handleButtonClicked()` should call the object's slot.

Comment: @smr answer is the correct answer. i.e. `Button { onClicked: buttonHandler.handleButtonClicked() }`